# Updating XML value using .modify in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-update

We are trying to update the value for isEnabled (to True) in a xml column. We have tried different methods of updating by following the similar questions asked earlier in SO and were unsuccessful.

Below is the **SQLFiddle** link.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d48ba8/7/0

Any help would be appreciated.

--XML data

```
   <Communication>
   <EventTypes>
   <EventType>
    <IsEnabled>false</IsEnabled>
    <Name>HK</Name> 
  </EventType>
  </EventTypes>
  </Communication>
  </ReimbursementProfile>

--Script to Update
UPDATE 
   Table2
SET 
   XMLCol.modify('replace value of (/ReimbursementProfile/Communication/EventTypes/EventType/IsEnabled/text())[1] with ("true")')

WHERE
   ID = 1

[![Actual Stucture of the XML File][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrOhd.png

Additional where condition for updating the actual XML value 
WHERE ProfileId =21599  and XmlValue.value('(/ReimbursementProfile/Communication/EventTypes/EventType/Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'Trip Log Entry Reminder'
```

Comment: The update statement works fine. Note: replace does not create the node/element if it does NOT exist. If the element does not exist you'll have to use .modify(insert...)

Comment: @lptr : We have added the actual XML structure of the file on which we are trying to update the value.
We have also added the additional where condition for the update for updating the actual XML value.

Comment: Can you show the **complete** set for the `<ReimbursementProfile>` top-level node? Are there any **XML namespaces** defined on it? That would explain why our `UPDATE` might not work ....

Answer (score 0):

The following will update the IsEnabled element of the first EventType with Name="Trip Log ...":

```
create table #Table2
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  ProfileId int,
  XMLCol xml
);

insert into #Table2 (ProfileId, XMLCol)
values
(21599 , N'
<ReimbursementProfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.testxmlupdate.com">
<Communication>
<EventTypes>

    <EventType>
    <IsEnabled>false</IsEnabled>
    <Name>HK</Name> 
    </EventType>

    <EventType> <!-- this is the first EventType with Name: Trip Log..., this will get updated/replaced modify[1]-->
    <IsEnabled>false</IsEnabled>   
    <Name>Trip Log Entry Reminder</Name> 
    </EventType>

    <EventType> <!-- this is the second EventType with Name: Trip Log..., this will NOT get updated, modify(replace on singletons) -->
    <IsEnabled>false</IsEnabled>
    <Name>Trip Log Entry Reminder</Name> 
    </EventType>

    <EventType>
    <IsEnabled>false</IsEnabled>
    <Name>HK</Name> 
    </EventType>

</EventTypes>
</Communication>
</ReimbursementProfile>
');


select 'before the update', *
from #Table2;


UPDATE 
   #Table2
SET 
   XMLCol.modify('replace value of (/ReimbursementProfile/Communication/EventTypes/EventType[Name="Trip Log Entry Reminder"]/IsEnabled/text())[1] with ("true")')
WHERE
   ProfileId = 21599
and XMLCol.exist ('/ReimbursementProfile/Communication/EventTypes/EventType[Name="Trip Log Entry Reminder"]') /* ...append:  /IsEnabled[. != "true"] ..?? */  = 1;

select 'after the update', *
from #Table2;


--clean-up
drop table #Table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The update is working fine as suggested by @marc_s, update was not being done due to the namespace. After explicitly mentioning the namespace the update works fine, unfortunately we cannot share the exact namespace.

The updated code is given below.

```
with xmlnamespaces(default '<URLOfNameSpace>')
 UPDATE 
 ProfileXmlValues
SET 
   XmlValue.modify('replace value of (/ReimbursementProfile/Communication/EventTypes/EventType[Id=102]/IsEnabled[. != "true"]/text())[1] with ("true")')
WHERE

and XmlValue.exist ('/ReimbursementProfile/Communication/EventTypes/EventType[Id=102]/IsEnabled[. != "true"]')  = 1;
```